# What do the numbers shown when a character is introduced mean?

Tags: touken-ranbu

In *Touken Ranbu: Hanamaru*, whenever a new character is introduced, a bit of information about the character is displayed on screen - their name, what type of sword they are, and a number. For example, when Tsurumaru is introduced in episode 2, we find that he is numbered "23".

[image: "23 - Tachi" / "Tsurumaru Kuninaga"]

What do these numbers mean?

Comment: could it be his class roster number?

Comment: Are they... in a class?

Comment: I have no idea, just suggesting what I know it could potentially mean.

Comment: It's not the age, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Touken Ranbu Hanamaru Wikia](http://touken-ranbu.wikia.com/wiki/Touken_Ranbu_Hanamaru), it's the order of sword arrivals in the Hanamaru Citadel.

The full list of the characters in order of their arrival:

> 17. Yamatonokami Yasusada (the main character)
>
> 1. Kashuu Kiyomitsu (Starter)
> 2. Heshikiri Hasebe
> 3. Imanotsurugi
> 4. Maeda Toushirou
> 5. Nikkari Aoe
> 6. Hachisuka Kotetsu
> 7. Mutsunokami Yoshiyuki
> 8. Namazuo Toushirou
> 9. Kasen Kanesada
> 10. Souza Samonji
> 11. Yagen Toushirou
> 12. Shokudaikiri Mitsutada
> 13. Gokotai
> 14. Yamanbagiri Kunihiro
> 15. Shishiou
> 16. Ishikirimaru
>
> 18. Akita Toushirou
> 19. Midare Toushirou
> 20. Nakigitsune
> 21. Aizen Kunitoshi
> 22. Doudanuki Masakuni
> 23. Tsurumaru Kuninaga
> 24. Hirano Toushirou
> 25. Honebami Toushirou
> 26. Atsushi Toushirou
> 27. Sayo Samonji
> 28. Uguisumaru
> 29. Horikawa Kunihiro
> 30. Taroutachi
> 31. Jiroutachi
> 32. Izuminokami Kanesada
> 33. Ookurikara
> 34. Mikazuki Munechika
> 35. Hakata Toushirou
> 36. Yamabushi Kunihiro
> 37. Otegine
> 38. Kousetsu Samonji
> 39. Urashima Kotetsu
> 40. Ichigo Hitofuri
> 41. Tonbokiri
> 42. Nihongou
> 43. Kogitsunemaru
> 44. Iwatooshi
> 45. Hotarumaru
> 46. Akashi Kuniyuki
> 47. Nagasone Kotetsu